# Convert kinect RGB and depth values to XYZ coordinates

Tags: matlab, coordinates, kinect, color-depth

I'm looking for an easy way to Convert kinect RGB and depth values to XYZ coordinates
using MATLAB.
My goal is a function with an input of: RGB and depth values of each point taking by **Kinect** camera, and output of: x,y and z values of each point.

[RGB, depth] = RGB_D2XYZ(XYZ)

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look to this great article. They have a function call DepthToCloud.m. You just need to be sure to pass Image center and top-left corner.

They are using Kinect too, so you don't really need to change a lot of parameter.

The article can be found [here](http://www.cs.washington.edu/rgbd-dataset/software.html)

**EDIT**

You can use mexopencv or OpenCV Matlab wrapper, to capture image and to do calibration. After OpenCV have a great function call `reporjectImageTo3D`. But this function need matrix `Q`. It's the projection matrix. Have a look to OpenCV documentation if you want to do by this way. Else depthToCloud is really good too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexandre, this is very helpful !