# Offline point cloud creation from Kinect V2 RGB and Depth images

Tags: matlab, kinect, point-clouds

I have a saved set of data captured with a Kinect V2 using the Kinect SDK. Data are in the form of RGB image, depth image, and colored point cloud. I used C# for this.

Now I want to create the point cloud separately using only the saved color and depth images, but in Matlab.

The [pcfromkinect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcfromkinect.html) Matlab function requires a live Kinect. But I want to generate the point cloud without a connected Kinect.

Any idea please.

I found the following related questions, but none of them have a clear clue.

- [Convert kinect RGB and depth values to XYZ coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497445/convert-kinect-rgb-and-depth-values-to-xyz-coordinates)
- [How to Convert Kinect rgb and depth images to Real world coordinate xyz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521468/how-to-convert-kinect-rgb-and-depth-images-to-real-world-coordinate-xyz)
- [generate a point cloud from a given depth image-matlab Computer Vision System Toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967842/generate-a-point-cloud-from-a-given-depth-image-matlab-computer-vision-system-to)

Answer (score 2):

I have done the same for my application. So here a brief overview what i have done:

**Save the data (C#/Kinect SDK):**

How to save a depth Image:

```
    MultiSourceFrame mSF = (MultiSourceFrame)reference;
    var frame = mSF.DepthFrameReference.AcquireFrame();

    if (frame != null )
    {
        using (KinectBuffer depthBuffer = frame.LockImageBuffer())
        {
            Marshal.Copy(depthBuffer.UnderlyingBuffer, targetBuffer,0, DEPTH_IMAGESIZE);
        }

        frame.Dispose();
 }
```

write buffer to file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + fileName, targetBuffer.Buffer);
```

For fast saving think about a ringbuffer.

**ReadIn the data (Matlab)**

how to get z_data:

```
fid = fopen(fileNameImage,'r');
img= fread(fid[IMAGE_WIDTH*IMAGE_HEIGHT,1],'uint16');
fclose(fid);
img= reshape(img,IMAGE_WIDTH,MAGE_HEIGHT);
```

how to get XYZ-Data:

For that think about the pinhole-model-formula to convert uv-coordinates to xyz
([formula](https://visualservoing.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/pinhole-model-formula.jpg)).

To get the cameramatrix K you need to calibrate your camera ([matlab calibration app](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html)) or get the cameraparameters from Kinect-SDK (`var cI= kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper.GetDepthCameraIntrinsics();`).

**`coordinateMapper` with the SDK**:

The way to get XYZ from Kinect SDK directly is quite easier. For that this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn785530.aspx) could help you. Just get the buffer by kinect sdk and convert the rawData with the `coordinateMapper` to xyz. Afterwards save it to  csv or txt, so it is easy for reading in matlab.

Comment: The code for obtaining z_data does not work. There is a problem with missing braces.